# Apache Web Server, Java Web Services - Hello World Tutorial

Tags: java, apache, web-services, web

Does anyone know where I can find a good tutorial for setting up apache and a java web service (Hello World)?

I'm new to Apache and Java Web Services (do I need Tomcat?).  I need a simple Java Web Service that can receive a simple http request from a client (eg. www.somedomain.com/service/001/notify).  The idea is that a client will make an Http request and the Java Web Service will receive the request and run corresponding Java code on the host.

Sorry for the gaps in my knowledge, hence my need to have a tutorial.

In short I'd like to do this:

CLIENT:

```
new Request("www.somedomain.com/service/001/notify");
```

JAVA WEB SERVICE:

```
public void notify(int serviceID){
    System.out.println("Service " + serviceID + " says 'Hello!'");
}
```

Comment: You want a web application or web services tutorial?

Comment: Do you mean Apache Tomcat ? It will be way more difficult with Apache alone...

Comment: I think I need Tomcat, I need the simplest way possible to perform the task above.  I've editted my question to be more clear.

Comment: Check out this link http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/threeminutes.html

Comment: I'm glad that you got some answers, but there's no real concrete problem to solve here. This really is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This video is slightly outdated; but it is a good tutorial for an absolute beginner](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOkN5IPoJVs).

Also, Tomcat is what is called a servlet container.  To see the difference between servlet containers and web services, here is a useful thread: [Difference between servlet and web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930795/difference-between-servlet-and-web-service)

You should keep in mind that Tomcat is just one of the many options out there.  If you're required to use it for school/work then go for it.  But if you have the freedom to chose then I would recommend using google app engine java (tutorial here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/ ).  Under the hood they use Derby (I think most of Google's products run on Derby but I don't know that for sure).

The reason I'm recommending because out of my experience with setting up servlets/etc app engine so far has been the easiest.  It also has a free hosting quota which you should be able to stay under since this is obviously going to be a trivial/learning experience.  In terms of which servlet containers are better than others I don't think its going to matter at your level of exposure.  Even though I've been messing around with them for a few years now it doesn't really matter to me either...

Comment: I haven't been back here for quite some time, until one day (today) I stumbled upon my same question.  The video tutorial was useful.  Thanks.